# How can I query the postgres Point type from clojureql?

Tags: postgresql, clojure, spatial, postgis

How can I query the postgres Point type from clojureql? I wish to use the PostGIS functionality but clojureql does not seem to include this.

Comment: Do you know what type gets returned if you query the table? Maybe try (class returned-object) to find out, then you can look at the associated JavaDoc

Comment: Yes, you are right. A point type is returned. Thanks. If you write that as the answer I will accept it.

Comment: The data type `point` is implemented in standard PostgreSQL, PostGis is not involved so far. This question turned out not to be a question at all, just several misunderstandings at once.

Comment: You think this might get more traction at [gis.se]?

Answer (score 2):

I am not an expert in clojureql, but if this syntax is correct:

```
(with-connection db 
   (with-query-results rs ["select * from blogs"] 
     ; rs will be a sequence of maps, 
     ; one for each record in the result set. 
     (dorun (map #(println (:title %)) rs))))
```

(taken from [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Clojure_Programming/Examples/JDBC_Examples#SELECT))

why not trying to change the rs into:

```
select point[0] as x, point[1] as y from table
```

Will this work? I am not sure it will, but if this Clojure way of querying is simply forwarding the query to the DB "asis" you might try using as well PostGIS operators in it.